# linux - create a folder shortcut

Tags: linux, apache, unix, centos

in html directory i have 2 domains,

```
example1.com
example2.com
```

in both of them there is a folder called files

```
example1.com/files
example2.com/files
```

I add in those folders same video files and my disk is full (coz i add same videos twice)

so is there a way to create a shortcat example i to add files to
html/example1.com/files 
 and html/example2.com/files will use those files from example1

i tried this command

```
ln -s /html/example1.com/files /html/example2.com/files
```

but i get this error if i visit example2.com/files/video.mp4

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /services/tmp/1.html on this server.
Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at example2.com Port 80
```

is there any other command that can do this

Answer (score 0):

there is simple solution , just run this command

```
mount --bind /html/example1.com/files /html/example2.com/files
```